# Wake On LAN using Magic packets is not working in Windows 10

Tags: bios, network-adapter, wake-on-lan, windows-10

Even after configuring all the settings like

- Network Adapter Settings
- BIOS setting
- Disabled Fast Startup
- Telnet and Port Settings

I can't able to wake up the machine with Windows 10 OS. Is there any support required from the N/w drivers or BIOS for Windows 10.
(Machine model: Dell Latitude)

Comment: Sounds like you will have to contact Dell so they can provide updated device drivers that support Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure that is right. From the wiki: "Wake-on-LAN support is implemented on the motherboard of a computer and the network interface (firmware), and is consequently not dependent on the operating system running on the hardware." Since WoL can also be used to power on a computer that is off and not booted, it makes sense it wouldn't be able to rely on the OS.

Comment: Are you sure the destination MAC address of your magic packet is correct?

Comment: @ssnobody yep. even I have tried with all formats and various WOL tools.

Comment: Are you sure you've really entered the [sleep state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564575(v=vs.85).aspx)? If you aren't entering the sleep state, it's likely @Ramhound suggestion to get new drivers is a good one since the docs state: "If any driver does not support system power management, individual devices can sleep and wake, but the power manager cannot put the system as a whole into a sleeping state."

Comment: @ssnobody - You are right to a point.  However....Those states and that firmware are both controlled by drivers.

Comment: Maybe try http://www.profshutdown.com/wakeonlan_troubleshoot.aspx and/or http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-monitor.aspx while system is up.

Comment: Were you able to test that the machine was able to receive the WOL packets while awake?

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the option "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" under Control Panel –> Hardware and Sound –> Power Options ->Choose what the power buttons do in windows, and it will work.
This is because with the above options the windows do not actually shutdown but go into a hybrid state of hibernation/sleep.

Comment: That doesn’t mean WoL won’t work, though. It’s also a hybrid of shutdown/hibernation. S3 is not involved.

Comment: It seems that this mode cuts the power from all "external" components. This means that the ethernet card is not working at all (i checked it from my switch were the led from the specific port when i had this enabled was shut but when i change it the it remained opened). This is not S3 (In these states (S1-S3), volatile memory is kept refreshed to maintain the system state. Some components remain powered so the computer can wake from input from the keyboard, LAN, or a USB device.) but an S5 ( 
The system appears to be off. This state is comprised of a full shutdown and boot cycle.)

Comment: Yeah, so? WoL works even in S5. It would be quite pointless otherwise. Whether WoL works at all depends on your firmware (BIOS/UEFI) and drivers.

Comment: WOL is supported from sleep (S3) or hibernate (S4). It is not supported from fast startup or soft off (S5) shutdown states. NICs are not armed for wake in these states because users do not expect their systems to wake up on their own.

Comment: More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So your method of disabling Fast Startup is actually disabling WoL as “supported” by Windows. ;) Also, you probably saw the note on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on 8 and now 10 also.

Try doing a shutdown through command prompt. When I use `shutdown /s /t 0` in command Wake-on-LAN works.

Answer (score 0):

I could only get WOL to work on a Dell optiplex by putting it to 'sleep' rather than a full shutdown. Works fine then. Power goes off on the system but the network card stays active .

Comment: I hate to say this but it does work on Optiplexes. What model do you have. It works on a 3040 and before that I had a 3020 and before that a 3010. Unless your Optiplex is really, really old. Are your NIC LEDs in the state I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

WoL is the feature of the motherboard and network card so the Windows settings shouldn't matter. If machine is powered off (either in S4 or S5 state) Windows is far from being able to affect anything.

You say you are using Dell Latitude notebook. Are you using wired connection? [It is tricky for notebooks to support wake-over-wireless.](https://www.dell.com/community/Networking-Internet-Bluetooth/Can-t-get-Wake-on-Wireless-LAN-WoWLAN-to-work-on-Latitude-D830/td-p/3158476) . But if you do use wired connection, make sure your BIOS supports it. Usually if the motherboard supports WoL there is a switch to turn on and off this feature in BIOS settings.

Answer (score -1):

I played with it a while back and did get it to work on a Optiplex 3040. Tried a few others and the only problem child I found was a Vostro 230. I woke my Optiplex 3040 up from a dead power off with Team Viewer. What are you using? One of the biggest diags I was given is that when it is turned off you should still have an activity LED on the NIC be active. If it isn't something isn't set up right. Usually the BIOS Power Management Settings. I'll reboot my Optiplex and write them down for you.

Comment: I had to re-do it because I keep switching computers but it does work. In the BIOS there were two settings under Power Management. Wake on LAN/WAN I set to LAN and WAN. Then there was a Deep Sleep Control I had to disable. At that point when I did a shutdown the Link LED on the NIC was solid Orange and the Activity LED occasionally flickered Amber. That is how you know if it is set up properly. Mine is a Optiplex 3040. Windows 10 Professional X64. TeamViewer powered it up from a shutdown. Didn't have to change a thing in the OS.